# Checking for string format using regex

Tags: python, regex, string

This is an easy question, but I am still getting stuck. I have a bunch of files and I have to check whether they are following this format.

```
abc_monthname[0-9]_v[0-9].xlsx
```

I have done some very generic like : `r^[A-Za-z]+_[A-Za-z0-9]+_v[0-9]+\.xlsx$''`
but this will fail for some cases. I want to give a strict rule. How do I achieve this in python?

Comment: For future reference, please avoid changing your question after answers have already been given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `+` quantifiers with the numeric portion of your regex:

```
^abc_monthname[0-9]+_v[0-9]+\.xlsx$
```

Note also that dot is a metacharacter and should be escaped with backslash.  Here is a sample script

```py
filename = "^abc_monthname123_v2.xslx"
if re.search(r'^abc_monthname[0-9]+_v[0-9]+\.xlsx$', filename):
    print("MATCH")
```

Comment: Something like :^[A-Za-z]+_[A-Za-z0-9]+_v[0-9]+\.xlsx$ 
Is this right?

Comment: The answer to your question totally depends on what you are trying to match.